# Can't Update database with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern

I'm learning asp.net WebApi and EFCore (CodeFirst) and as an exercise, I'm building Warehouse Api and my update method doesn't work.
This is my repository code:

```
public void Update(T toUpdate)
        {
            if(toUpdate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Entity is null");

            T tmp = GetById(toUpdate.Id);
            tmp = toUpdate;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

and this is my Service code:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(UpdateEmployeeCommand command)
        {
            UpdateEmployeeCommandValidator validator = new UpdateEmployeeCommandValidator();
            var results = validator.Validate(command);
            if (!results.IsValid)
            {
                throw new CommandValidationException(results.Errors.Select(x => new CommandValidationError
                {
                    ErrorCode = x.ErrorCode,
                    ErrorMessage = x.ErrorMessage,
                    PropertyName = x.PropertyName
                }));
            }
            _repository.Update(new Employee()
            {
                Id = command.Id,
                FirstName = command.FirstName,
                Address = command.Address,
                LastName = command.LastName,
                Age = command.Age,
                Email = command.Email,
                PhoneNumber = command.PhoneNumber
            });
        }
```

and this is how I use it in Controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmployee(int Id, UpdateEmployeeCommand command)
        {
            if(Id != command.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var employeeModelFromRepo = _repository.GetById(Id);
            if(employeeModelFromRepo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _employeeService.UpdateEmployee(command);

            return NoContent();
        }
```

When I call UpdateEmployee, it runs without any error but it doesn't update my database.

I'm new to this, so this might be an easy fix.

Comment: You need to copy new values to tmp, not just reassign the variable.

Comment: Try `db.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate)

Comment: @GuruStron `db.Update(toUpdate)` gives me an error but `db.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate)` work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this generic update function:

```
public virtual T Update(T t) where T : class, IBaseEntity // contains Id as primary key
        {
            if (t == null)
                return null;
            var exist = Context.Set<T>().Find(t);

          // Or you can try 
           var exist = Context.Set<T>()
                    .Where(i=>i.Id=t.Id).FirstOrdDefault();

            if (exist == null) return exist;
            Context.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
            Context.SaveChanges();

            return exist;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you forget to call your service method in the controller end-point? `UpdateEmployee()`

Comment: I've done that the first time I tried updating the database but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Commented solution works, i just had to add `db.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate)` to the repository code.